# Windows form breaks when calling Task.Result

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have code similar to following inside my Windows form:

```
private async Task<string> GetGreetingAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => "Hello");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = GetGreetingAsync().Result;
}
```

Clicking the button causes the entire Windows form to freeze and become unresponsive. No exception is thrown.

Even when I don't use the task `.Result` directly in the event handler and the whole `async` marked code is in some class library function, which provides interface without `async`, the problem still occurs. Unit tests for such class library pass without any problems, but when I call its function from event handler on Windows form, it breaks and does not respond.

**Why does this happen? How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are blocking the the UI thread with `.Result;` (see `ConfigureAwait`)

```
private async Task<string> GetGreetingAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => "Hello").ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = GetGreetingAsync().Result;
}
```

**Or** go all the way async

```
private async Task<string> GetGreetingAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => "Hello");
}

async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = await GetGreetingAsync();
}
```

Using this version you don't even need to *await* in  `GetGreetingAsync`

```
private Task<string> GetGreetingAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => "Hello");
}

async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = await GetGreetingAsync();
}
```

Comment: @tomp it depends on the **synchronization context** of your code. It would work in a console app(without *ConfigureAwait*) but not in winforms app. It is a huge topic to explain in comments (and with my limited english)

Comment: Okay, now I know what topic to look up :) Thank you.

Comment: @tomp, stephen cleary explains it succintly here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `await` instead of `Result` on a `Task<T>` to get non-blocking behavior.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = await GetGreetingAsync();
}
```

Calling `Result` causes the code to wait until the `Task` has completed where calling `await` allows the async behavior to be used.

**Edit**

Actually looking at your code again if you're doing

```
private async Task<string> GetGreetingAsync()
{
  return await new Task<string>(() => "Hello");
}
```

That is really not needed. That block can just be

```
private Task<string> GetGreetingAsync()
{
  return new Task<string>(() => "Hello");
}
```

There's no need for the thing returning the task to be `async`.

Comment: The thing is that I don't care about the non-blocking behavior in this use-case. I expected that the code will wait until the task finishes. Why did the form become unresponsive and the entire application broke?

Comment: Because the UI thread is a single thread. So when you block the UI thread the application becomes unresponsive. You do care about the non-blocking behavior if you don't want your application to become unresponsive.

Comment: I don't care if it becomes unresponsive until the task finishes. That is what I would expect in this behavior. The thing is that the application stops working and never starts working again. That is what is bugging me: Why does it never start working again?