# Rebus MSMQ Centralized Storage

Tags: rebus

When enabling centralized storage with MSMQ, is there anything else that needs to change? Here's what I have, but the code will not fully load. Works as expected if I disable centralized storage.

```
_messageActivator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator();
_messageActivator.Register<PosOnlineHandler>(() => new PosOnlineHandler(WriteOutputAsync));
_messageActivator.Register<PumpDownHandler>(() => new PumpDownHandler(WriteOutputAsync));
_messageActivator.Register<MetersRequestHandler>(() => new MetersRequestHandler(WriteOutputAsync, _messageActivator.Bus));
_messageActivator.Register<CreditAuthorizationHandler>(() => new CreditAuthorizationHandler(WriteOutputAsync, _messageActivator.Bus));
Configure.With(_messageActivator)
   .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("consumerServiceQueue"))
   .Routing(r => r.TypeBased()
      .Map<PumpDownEvent>("publisherServiceQueue")
      .Map<PosOnlineEvent>("publisherServiceQueue")
      .Map<MetersResponse>("publisherServiceQueue")
      .Map<CreditAuthorizationResponse>("publisherServiceQueue"))
   .Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInSqlServer(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False", "RebusSubscriptions", true, true))
   .Start();
   _messageActivator.Bus.Subscribe<PumpDownEvent>().Wait();
   _messageActivator.Bus.Subscribe<PosOnlineEvent>().Wait();
```

Thanks.
Scott C.

Comment: what do you mean by "the code will not fully load"?

Comment: Sorry, it hangs on Subscriber().Wait(). ....,I see that the MessageBus sample uses centralized MSMQ storage so I'll test that later to see if I get the same result.

Comment: and it doesn't time out after 30 seconds or 1 minute or something?

Comment: Nope. It just continues to hang there when isCentralized is enabled. The MessageBus sample works fine, so it's apparently something I'm doing in my code. I downloaded the Rebus code so I could debug, but not able to build the Rebus solution yet.

Comment: is the code executed when the application is initialized? or does it happen on a WPF thread or on an ASP.NET request thread?

Comment: The code above is called from the constructor of a windows forms app.

Comment: That explains it :) when you call `.Wait()` on a `Task` it will block the current thread, waiting for the task to finish. But the task scheduler in Windows Forms apps dispatches continuations back on the UI thread, effectively causing a deadlock. You can read more in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23036287/6560)

Comment: Rebus 3 will have a synchronous API (accessible via `bus.Advanced.SyncBus`) which you can then use in situations like this when it is released. For now I suggest you investigate what is the recommended way of running something `async` during the initialization of a Windows Forms form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an explanation: Windows Forms (which you mentioned that you are calling this code from) uses a task scheduler that insists on running continuations on the UI thread.

This is pretty useful in a Windows Forms context, because controls may only be manipulated from that thread.

The problem arises when you call `.Wait()` (or `.Result`) on a `Task`, because that blocks the current thread, waiting for all continuations to finish executing – but since the current thread is blocked, it will never be available for running continuations, thus resulting in a deadlock.

Here's [another question that discusses this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036075/windows-form-breaks-when-calling-task-result). As you can see, the issue is in no way specific for Rebus, it is simply a general trait of the mix of async `Task`s and Windows Forms (or WPF or ASP.NET for that matter).

I suggest you investigate how to properly run `async` code during the initialization of a `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, so you can establish your subscriptions in the recommended way by `await`ing the `Task`s:

```
await bus.Subscribe<PumpDownEvent>();

await bus.Subscribe<PosOnlineEvent>();
```

---

**Why does this issue only show when `isCentralized: true` is passed to the `StoreInSqlServer` configuration method?**

Simply put, it's because nothing truly asynchronous actually happens when Rebus is configured to use decentralized subscription storage with MSMQ as the transport.

When running **centralized**, the subscriber registers itself as a subscriber in the subscription storage. With the configuration you are using, that means that an `SqlConnection` gets (asynchronously) opened, and then an `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` is (again asynchronously) executed, inserting a row in the `[RebusSubscriptions]` table.

When running **decentralized**, the subscriber registers itself as a subscriber by sending the publisher a [`SubscribeRequest`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Messages/Control/SubscribeRequest.cs). *With MSMQ this operations just happens to execute synchronously without `await`ing a single thing*, because MSMQ does not have an API that returns `Task`s.

If you had used SQL Server, Azure Service Bus, Amazon SQS, etc. as the transport, there would have been some asynchronous stuff going down when sending the `SubscribeRequest`, and then you would have gotten the same deadlock.

I hope that explains it :)

Comment: Thanks Mookid. Any insight as to why this only comes up when IsCentralized is set to true?

Comment: Excellent question! :) I have extended the answer with an explanation....